# How to block network access for conda/python environments?

Tags: anaconda

How can I configure a virtual data science environment so that data science libraries from NumFocus do not contact external servers without explicit consent?

After setting up a custom DNS I observed traffic when initializing a conda environment. I would like to avoid this for individual projects/ environments while working with licensed data.

Comment: This is actually a technical question. I recommend you to move it to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could look at using a Docker image with an Anaconda distribution, which block the network ports unless you specifically open them with the -p option.

You could try this page for starters: https://hub.docker.com/u/continuumio